# address randomization: print address of a static var in c

Tags: c, static, virtual-memory

I am reading an OS textbook, there is an example the verify whether the system is supporting virtual addresses and says the following program should print the same result every time. I see some difference on my macbook pro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var = 0;
int main(void)
{
  var += 1;
  printf("Address: %x, value: %d\n", &var, var);
  return 0;
}
```

when run it I see the address changes in some bytes(not all of them however):

```
./main
Address: e8c6018, value: 1
./main
Address: 9032018, value: 1
./main
Address: 1bc7018, value: 1
```

When I run in GDB, I always see 1018:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/xilan/temp/main
Address: 1018, value: 1
[Inferior 1 (process 19631) exited normally]
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/xilan/temp/main
Address: 1018, value: 1
[Inferior 1 (process 19636) exited normally]
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/xilan/temp/main
Address: 1018, value: 1
[Inferior 1 (process 19654) exited normally]
```

So what the different in running it directly and in GDB ? Why I see the address varies when run it directly ?

Comment: The book is outdated, it didn't think about [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: It does mention ASLR, so my system even randomizes the locations of static variables ?

Comment: At the level where ASLR is implemented, I don't think the OS cares exactly what is going into the particular page of memory it is creating a mapping for. A "static variable" is just "something in writable memory", basically.

Comment: @user2018791 a  static variable is relative to the address which OS loaded an executable, so if OS load an executable in random address it will affect on the static variable too.

Comment: I believe ASLR is applied as part of the virtual memory mapping. The physical addresses (of bss, data etc) will remain the same, but you'll get randomized virtual addresses.

Comment: @user2018791 It doesn't randomize the locations of variables. It randomizes where the whole program is loaded. This is why the printed addresses don't change in the last three hexadecimal digits when printed.

Answer (score 2):

Your book is old. Many operating systems today are randomising where programs and libraries are loaded to make things just a bit more secure against certain attacks.

MacOS randomises where programs are loaded in memory. It does disable that randomisation for gdb though, this is why the address looks the same in gdb all the time.

Answer (score 2):

In **GDB**, we always get the **same address**, even run with different processes, but The normal behavior should be like below, if run directly in Linux

```
./main
Address: e8c6018, value: 1
./main
Address: 9032018, value: 1
./main
Address: 1bc7018, value: 1
```

Because This is due to the fact that in **GDB**, the **disable-randomization** is turned **on** by **default**. It should be turned **off** if we expect regular output:

```
set disable-randomization off
```

Reference link : http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/set_disable-randomization